# How much security does Android encryption provide for turned on devices?

Tags: encryption

In case my device is stolen it probably will be turned on. How secure are my data when this happens with Android 10 and file based encryption (https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based?hl=en)?

Comment: That depends on the protection you have selected (pattern/PIN/password). If the pattern or PIN can be guessed easily (e.g. by smudge of your fingers on the display) any protection measures won't help.

Comment: very secure. your device is protected against bruteforce https://source.android.com/security/authentication/gatekeeper